# XCode 4.5.2 hangs when archiving

Tags: xcode, archive

Recently I've updated my OS to mountain lion due to xcode update 
as well as xcode ofcourse. I think this caused some kind of problem

1. I've tried changing LLVM
2. I've tried skip install YES/NO
3. I've tried changing provisionings
4. I've tried re-installing XCode
5. I've tried restarting my Mac
6. I've tried another project
7. I've tried "sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
8. Tried going back to 4.5.1 Still doesn't work

But still XCode is stuck, see below. 
Almost at the end of archiving for hours.

Has anyone suggestions please?

[image]

Comment: it's a disaster tried 4.5.1 and still doesn't work TT